# Problem with old genius digital drawing tablet, ubuntu 16.10

Tags: graphics-tablet

I have a old genius tablet. It works fine on ubuntu 16.04, but on Ubuntu 16.10 don't work.

On Linux Deepen and Win10, the tablet work fine too.

The tablet no draw. Look likes it have not pressure. I test in Krita, gimp and MyPaint.

I search about fix this, but I don't find nothig. I hope somebody can help me.

xinput --list

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Pen                 id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
ImPS/2 BYD TouchPad                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 5543:0004 UC-Logic Technology Corp. Tablet WP5540U
```

xinput list-props "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Pen"

```
Device Enabled (143):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (271): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (272):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (273):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (274):    10.000000
Device Product ID (264):    21827, 4
Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event13"
Evdev Axis Inversion (275): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (276):   <no items>
Evdev Axes Swap (277):  0
Axis Labels (278):  "Abs X" (268), "Abs Y" (269), "Abs Pressure" (270)
Button Labels (279):    "Button Unknown" (267), "Button Unknown" (267), "Button Unknown" (267), "Button Wheel Up" (149), "Button Wheel Down" (150), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (151), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (152)
Evdev Scrolling Distance (280): 0, 0, 0
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (281):    1
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (282):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (283): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (284): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (285):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (286):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (287):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (288):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (289):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (290):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (291): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (292):  0
```

And MyPaint Device Test

```
MOTION_NOTIFY x=636.00 y=260.00 pressure=0.0000 drawWindow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

There is a bug on `xserver-xorg-input-evdev-1:2.10.2` that specifically affect pressure, it is not reported from kernel evdev to xserver-xorg-evdev:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1639337

Acording to one of the comments, the solution is to downgrade to `xserver-xorg-input-evdev-1:2.10.1`, please help by adding yourself as one of the affected users on the list, so this can be properly corrected (the package being updated to a newer version).

**How to downgrade the package**

Get the older package here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xserver-xorg-input-evdev (if x86 64 bits it is `amd64`, if x86 32 bits, `i386`)

After that you should open the terminal and do:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i path/to/xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.10.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb.deb
```

adjusting the path to the correct folder. Finaly, force the package to not upgrade:

```
sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

You will need to pay attention to this bug, so you remove the mark when it is solved (on the same bug link find where to put yourself on the mailing list for changes)

> **Again, It is not the best solution, specially at this case there is no visible counter effects, but this kind of forceful downgrade generally result on many broken packages if not an broken system , so please consider going to the bug report and add yourself to the list of affected persons so this bug gain more relevance and get corrected quicker.**

Comment: Ty  Romulo. I am using now Ubuntu mate 16.04.2 with kernel 4.4.0.71  and Linux Mint 18.1. The tablet is working perfect, but I want use Ubuntu Mate 17.04 in the future. I will write my bug in the launchpad website jeje. Ty for the solution.

Comment: Hi, I confirm the bug in the lanchpad website. Ty

Comment: No problem, I was facing the same problem with my huion h610 pro and wasn't interested in reverting back to a 16.04 snapshot. 17.04 is not affected by what I can see, xserver-xorg-input-evdev is newer.